# Do I have to change the cooking time when I cook homemade noodles?

Tags: noodles

I want to make my own egg noodles for a casserole dish. Do I have to adjust the cooking time? I have been told homemade noodles cook faster, does this mean I should add the noodles later? The recipe has to bake for 45 minutes. I do not want my noodles to be mushy.

Comment: Cooking time compared to what? Dry noodles or store bought fresh noodles? Are the noodles cooked *before* they are baked for 45 minutes? Please give us some additional information!

Comment: The noodles I was going to use are the uncooked ones that I buy at the store. The only thing that is pre-cooked is the hamburger. I think I will hold off on using my homemade noodle. I am going to make a small soup out of them. This way if they are not very good I wont mess up the whole dinner.

Comment: I suspect that your instinct is correct @GJ.Baker, I would try a small-scale test before committing to a large dish.

Answer (score 3):

Homemade noodles have a completely different texture from dried pasta.  The times I've made lasagne for friends with fresh spinach noodles, they were quite confused by the texture.  And even if there's lots of moisture and time for it to cook in the casserole, you need to boil them for 30 to 60 seconds or they'll disintegrate in the casserole.

Depending on the recipe, I might consider starting with everything already hot, the pasta boiled for a minute or so, assemble it, then put it under the broiler (grill, whatever you call 'top heat only' in your country) to get a bit of a crust on top, then let it sit for a few minutes to firm up some.